# Can't solve - list indices must be integers, not str - dictionary declaration

Tags: python, django

I've been on this for a few days and I can't seem to figure it out. I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
Stacktrace (most recent call last): 

File "django/core/handlers/base.py", line 112, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 22, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "locations/views.py", line 722, in servicerecords
    cur_loc = Location.objects.get(id=location_id)
```

urls.py

```
    url(r'^location/(?P<location_id>\d+)/servicerecservicerecords/$', 'locations.views.servicerecords',
   name='location_servicerecords'),
```

Here is the code thats running:

```
def servicerecords(request, location_id):
    RECORDS_PER_PAGE = 15
    modal_visible = False
    show_requests = 0
    cur_service_rec = None
    cur_service_request = None
    page=None
    service_request_page=None
    variables = {}

    if request.GET.get('show_requests', ''):
        show_requests = int(request.GET.get('show_requests'))

    if request.GET.get('page',''):
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        service_request_page = request.GET.get('page')

    cur_loc = Location.objects.get(id=location_id)
    variables['location'] = cur_loc
    variables['locid'] = location_id
    ....
    ....
```

Am I missing something? Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Comment: What are you passing as `location_id`?

Comment: Could it be that `location_id` is not an int? Log it and see.

Comment: Is this your exact code? also, can you post the entire stacktrace ? It doesnt look like the error is exactly happening on the line shown

Comment: @DavidReeve in sentry i see this: 'location_id' - u'100676'

Comment: Then mu's answer will solve your problem.

Comment: I tried it and still got he same error. Btw, do you still see his response on this question?

Comment: @karthikr that is the entrie stacktrace that I'm getting in Sentry. Where else can I go to get a more detailed stack trace. On my webpage its throwing a 500 error (this why i'm in sentry).

Comment: What does your url pattern for the view look like?

Comment: @Brandon     url(r'^location/(?P<location_id>\d+)/servicerecservicerecords/$', 'locations.views.servicerecords',
       name='location_servicerecords'),

Comment: OK cool. Just wanted to make sure you were using `\d+` for the parameter

Comment: Thanks. It is. I even tried what brsbilgic suggested and no luck either. My exception is now report a commented out line as where the error is coming from.

Comment: Is it possible to have a caching issue? I only ask because I have another non related error thats being throw with a URL name. However that name exists no where in my code. It was something old that I corrected. Could this error be reading and old list declaration?

Comment: I dug through the exception some more and found the the error is thrown in 
    django/core/handlers/base.py ? in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
    'e' : TypeError('list indices must be integers, not str',) 
'middleware_method': <bound method CsrfViewMiddleware.process_view of <django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware object at 0x261a490>>

Does that help any more? I'm still fighting with this

Answer (score 0):

```
cur_loc = Location.objects.get(id=int(location_id))
```

Not the safest way. You should check if it's integer ant catch if it's not etc. but basically it works

Comment: I tried this as well and i'm still getting the error.

Comment: location/(?P<location_id>[0-9]+)/servicerecservicerecords/ can you try this url

Comment: Still no luck. I actaully commenting out a line and now sentry throws the error on that commented line. I know its not there but this is weird.

Comment: Is it possible to have a caching issue? I only ask because I have another non related error thats being throw with a URL name. However that name exists no where in my code. It was something old that I corrected. Could this error be reading and old list declaration?

Comment: I'm not sure the problem with senty. You may remove all the lines and and just print something to console if it runs the right code block.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by restarting my server. I believe there is a deeper issue with my code files.

Thanks for all the help.